# Run Maven plugin just before deploy to remote repo

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

In my maven project I use the pgp plugin to sign my jars. I need to do this only when deploying to remote repo, but not when installing to local repo. So I tried to set the phase to deploy.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

With that configuration maven first deploys to remote repo and theh signs my jars...

I read that plugins are executed in the order they are defined in POM file, so I tried to configure deploy-plugin after sign plugin, but that didnt have any effect

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

How can I achieve that sign plugin is not executed on install, but on deploy before artifacts are uploaded? I'm using maven3.

Comment: Sounds a bit tricky... Shouldn't be the artifact be identical for local install and remote deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i would suggest to update [maven-gpg-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/) to an more up-to-date version cause this version 1.1 is of 2010..Apart from that i would suggest to keep the defaults of the plugins which means the [binding of maven-deploy-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) as the `deploy` life cycle and for the [maven-gpg-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html) the `verify` life cycle phase which is not ideal if you have integration tests. In such cases it makes sense to define a profile which is activated only in release cases to prevent confusions with integration test.

```xml
<plugin>
  <inherited>true</inherited>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>sign-artifacts</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>sign</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen project putting the `gpg-plugin` in `verify` phase.

May I know what version of Maven you are using? I believe the plugin in same phase should run in order it is defined, after Maven 2.0.10 (or probably earlier). However as `maven-deploy-plugin` is default binding for `deploy` phase, I am not clear if the ordering will be in effect